# Not Found Error

Tags: .htaccess, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am a newbie in .htaccess. This is my directory structure (folder name urshow)

```
    api
    -config
    -modules
    --v1
    ---controllers
    ---models
    -runtime
    -tests
    -web

    backend
    common
    console
    environments
    frontend
```

Inside controllers I have a controller named movies. This is my htaccess file inside  api/web

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~user/urshow/api/modules/v1/web/
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now when I try to run this url I get a "`not found error http://192.168.1.4/~user/urshow/api/web/movies`". What's wrong with my htaccess file?

Comment: What is your document root defined as in your virtualhost?

Comment: @PanamaJack where can i find that?

Comment: What is the main directory that your files are? Not including the subdirectories? is this a WAMP setup?

Comment: main directory path: /home/user/public_html/urshow/api

Comment: so is your document root `/home/user/public_html/`? did you create urshow and api folders?

Comment: yes it is my root and i have created folders

Comment: what folder is `index.php` located?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99282/discussion-between-bloodhound-and-panama-jack).